# Watch command "Refresh rate"

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, sense-hat

I am using a  Pi 3 Model B and a Sensehat. I am using the following command:

```
sudo watch -n 0.1 python sensors.py
```

My program runs fine and the command works, However I have one issue.

Even though I use `-n 0.1` the program does not "refresh" every 1/10 of a second. It seems to only refresh at an interval of 1 second and cannot refresh any faster regardless of what I type.

Is this because the Sensehat sensors refresh at an interval of 1 second or is there any way to force the watch command to refresh more frequently?

Answer (score 0):

Try the command `watch -n 0.1 date +%N` to see that watch can update 10 times per second.

It only updates the current time once a second.

Are you sure your script runs that fast?

What does `time python sensors.py` report for one run?

Comment: This is what I get: real    0m0.978s  
user    0m0.780s  
sys     0m0.090s

Comment: @Marco So your script takes just under a second to run.  You can't get updates faster unless you speed your script up.